# var returning undefined when trying to return data and cosole log shows data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hi here is the code im using

```
function get_last_chat_time(steamid){
if(!db_connect) {
    return 0;
}

chat_db.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match":{"name":"chat-msg",steamid: steamid}},
        { "$sort" : { date : -1 } },
        {"$limit" : 1}
    ]
).toArray(function(err, list){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error loading history from DB: " + err);
        } else {
            var i = list.length-1;
            var lasttime = Math.floor((new Date() - list[i].date)/1000);
            console.log(Math.floor((new Date() - lasttime)/1000));//this works perfect
           return lasttime;
        }

    });
}
console.log(get_last_chat_time(msg.steamid));// this is undefined
```

so basicly i want this function to return the value when i call function, when i do console log inside this toArray function its fine out side its not.
I just dont understand how to get this to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: tip: alter `console.log(get_last_chat_time(msg.steamid));` to `get_last_chat_time(msg.steamid);`

Comment: im not using jquery im using nodejs and mongo db , ive seen your link and its not helping me at all

Comment: @LucasCosta doing that is fine i can get console to give time as i have console log to check its there, it returns nothing at all out side the array function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting undefined values is because the **[`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)** cursor method is asynchronous, and can finish at any time. In your case, it is finishing after you're using `console.log()`, so the values are undefined when you're accessing them.

To fix this problem, you can only use the values inside the **[`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray)** function's callback. It would look something like this:

```
function get_last_chat_time(steamid, callback){
    if(!db_connect) {
        return callback(null, 0);
    }

    chat_db.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match":{"name":"chat-msg",steamid: steamid}},
            { "$sort" : { date : -1 } },
            {"$limit" : 1}
        ]
    ).toArray(function(err, list){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error loading history from DB: " + err);
                return callback(err);
            } 
            var i = list.length-1;
            var lasttime = Math.floor((new Date() - list[i].date)/1000);
            console.log(Math.floor((new Date() - lasttime)/1000));//this works perfect
            return callback(null, lasttime);

        });
}

get_last_chat_time(msg.steamid, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH, this helped me understand what i was doing wrong.